# How to be sure a file has been successfully written?

Tags: java, file, serialization, file-io, operating-system

I'm adding autosave functionality to a graphics application in Java. The application periodically autosaves the current document and also autosaves on exit. When the user starts the application, the autosave file is reloaded.

If the autosave file is corrupted in any way (I assume a power cut when the file is in the middle of being saved would do this?), the user will lose their work. How can I prevent such situations and do all I can to guarantee that the autosave document is in a consistent state?

To further complicate matters, to autosave the document I need to save one .xml file and several .png files. Also, the .png saving occurs in C code over JNI.

My current strategy is to write each .png with the extension .png.tmp, write the .xml file with the extension .xml.tmp, and then rename each file to remove the .tmp part leaving the .xml until last. On startup, I only load the autosave document if I can find a .xml file and ignore .xml.tmp files. I also don't delete the previous autosave document until the .xml.tmp file for the new document is renamed.

I guess my knowledge of what happens when you write to disk is poor. I know you can have software read/write buffers when using files, as well as OS and hardware buffers and that all of these need to be flushed. I'm confused how I can know for sure when something really has been written to disk and what I can do to protect myself. Does the renaming operation do anything to make sure buffers are flushed?

Comment: What is the cost of losing a file when power goes out?

Comment: Well, if the user spent X hours working on their document and it got corrupted, they would lose X hours of work. So it's critical this works correctly.

Comment: ~ not so much, no. If the power goes out they would expect to lose X hours of work if they didn't save it. Implement it as best you can (there's a really good solution below involving the use of two files and checksums) and just let that be enough. Now, if you're trying to offer a certain level for a cost, then you should be able to define the requirement that you'll be selling against. Otherwise, don't kill yourself looking for perfection.

Comment: It's just an application for painting things but some users might want to e.g. spent 10 or 20 hours on one piece of work. If they managed to lose their work, it would enrage them and generate complaints. A feature I want is that the user can undo the last 100 or so changes and they never have to explicitly save their work. In this case, you can't blame the user for not saving their progress. I hear what you're saying about being practical though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If the autosave file is corrupted in any way (I assume a power cut when the file is in the middle of being saved would do this?), the user will lose their work. How can I prevent such situations and do all I can to guarantee that the autosave document is in a consistent state?

To prevent loss of data due to partially written autosave file, don't overwrite the autosave file.  Instead, write to a new file each time, and then rename it once the file has been safely written.

To guard against not noticing that an autosave file has not been correctly written:

1. Pay attention to the exceptions thrown as the autosave file is written and closed in case a disc error, file system full, etc.
2. Keep a running checksum of the file as it is written and write it at the end of the file.  Then when you load the autosave file, check that the checksum is there and is correct.

If the checkpointed state involves multiple files, make sure that you write the files in a well known order (without overwriting!), and write the checksum on the autosave file after all of the other files have been safely closed.  You might want to create a directory for each checkpoint.

**FOLLOW UP**

No.  I'm not saying that rename always succeeds.  However, it *is* atomic - it either succeeds (and completes) or the file system is not changed.  So, if you do this:

1. write "file.new" and close,
2. delete "file",
3. rename "file.new" to "file"

then provided the first step succeeds you are guaranteed to have the latest "file" safely on disc.  And it is simple to add a couple of steps so that you have a backup of "file" at all times.  (If the 3rd step fails, you are left with "file.new" and no "file".  This can be recovered manually, or automatically by the application next time you run it.)

Also, I'm not saying that writes always succeed, or that applications don't crash, or that the power never goes off.  And the point of the checksum is to allow you to **detect** the cases where these things have happened and the autosave file is incomplete.

Finally, it is a good idea to have two autosaves in case your application gets itself into a state where its data structures are messed up and the last autosave is nonsensical as a result.  (The checksum won't protect against this.)  Be cautious about autosaving when the application crashes for the same reason.

Comment: So you're saying that the instant the rename operation succeeds, I'm 100% (or as well as I can) guaranteed that the autosave files have been written to disk? Why use a checksum? Doesn't the OS perform some kind of check to make sure read/writes succeed?

Comment: No the OS doesn't make sure read/writes succeed. There's no way to guarantee that without a checksum. Checksums can also be used to ensure no corruption, at the sacrifice of higher IO cost in both calculation and space. Waiting for the rename to succeed, however, indicates usually that the system has finished writing to the file (Windows won't let you rename a file being written to)

Comment: What you use a checksum for saving e.g. Office documents and similar things that are important to the user? I'm wondering if that would be overkill. I program for mobile devices too so the CPU overhead is higher there but the chance of power failure is probably higher too.

Comment: The overhead of calculating a running checksum while saving is probably too small to be relevant.

Comment: OK, but I'm just asking is it normal when writing document based applications that you store and check checksums? I'm wondering if I'm being too paranoid about corruption. I mean, you'd really want to write your autosave file and then immediately check the checksum of the written file to check for success. Otherwise you might end up with both of your autosave files being corrupt in the worst worst case scenario.

Comment: RichardNewton: If you write something and immediately read it back in (to check the checksum), what you read back will likely be from cache (RAM), in which case the checksum will be irrelevant.

Comment: *"I mean, you'd really want to write your autosave file and then immediately check the checksum of the written file to check for success."*.  My main reason for checksum is to detect incomplete files rather than files that have had bits flipped.  Reading back is unnecessary for that.  However, if one is worried about corruption on the media, then reading back is probably advisable ... with the fs cache turned off.

Comment: @RichardNewton the trick is that they're not going to be that upset over the loss of an autosave file on power loss.  Flukes happen. The best thing you can do is work to make sure your program doesn't crash on them (cos that sort of corruption will piss them off). You seem to think that people absolutely can't deal with the loss of a file due to freak circumstance, but they've been used to that for 25 years with no problem. They realize that computers are fallible. Most `people` don't even know that autosaves exist. I use my extended family of `200+ normal` people as my control there.

Comment: @RichardNewton: In a perfect OS, the *OS* would ensure that your data doesn't get corrupted.  But current OSs don't really do this.  A checksum is just a nice safeguard to add.

Comment: @drachenstern: for a good autosave system, you shouldn't know it exists until you need it.  I think people *do* expext a better system these days.  If Word crashes on me and I restart it, my unsaved document reappears right where I left it.  (It will be a little stale, but that's better than nothing!)

Comment: @Karmastan, that's my point! It'll be a little stale. I'm only saying you can't be perfect. Word defaults to every five minutes (and is configurable)

Comment: @drachenstern: it's still a long way from "can't be perfect" to "loss of a file."  Losing data is not just a fluke, it's the worst thing that can happen to a user.  Users will tolerate crashes, but not if it causes their data to disappear.

Comment: @karmastan ~ I think we see eye to eye on that. I'm just urging him to not try to be perfect. Users will accept SOME loss on an autosave. It's a fact of life that autosaves can only catch so much data. He should still use a rotating autosave with multiple files and checksums.

Comment: @karmastan - *"disabling file system caches seems overkill to me"* - please note that my suggestion is in the context of being worried about **media errors**; e.g. dodgy floppy discs or memory sticks.  I agree there's minimal value doing this for a regular hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, since you have several different files as part of this one document, consider using either a project directory to hold them all together, or using some encapsulation format (like .zip) to put them all inside one file.

What you want to do is *atomically* replace the old backup files with new ones.  Unfortunately, I don't believe that Java gives you enough control do this directly.  You also need to reason about what operations are atomic in the underlying operating system.  I know Linux file systems, so my answer will be biased towards a Java program running on that system.  I would be shocked if Windows didn't do the same thing, but I can't say for certain.

Most Linux file systems (e.g. the meta-data journaled ones) let you rename files atomically.  If the system crashes half-way through a rename, when you restart, it will be as if you never renamed a file in the first place.  For this reason, a common way to atomically update an existing file F is to write your new data to a temporary file T and then rename T to F.  Any system or application crash up to that rename will not affect F, so it will always be consistent.

Of course, before you rename, you need to make sure that your temporary file is consistent.  Make sure that all streaming buffers for the file are flushed to the OS (`Channel.force()` or `OutputStream.flush()`) and the OS buffers are flushed to the disk (`FileOutputStream.getFD.sync()`).  Of course, unless your OS disables the write cache *on the hard disk itself* (it probably hasn't), there's still a chance that your data can be corrupted.  Add a checksum to the XML if you really want to be really sure.  If you're truly paranoid, you should flush the OS and hard disk buffer caches and re-read the file to verify that it is consistent.  This is beyond any reasonable expectation for normal consumer applications.

But that's just to atomically write write a single file.  Your propblem is more complex: you have many files to update atomically.  For example, I'll say that you have two files, *img.png* and *main.xml*.  I'd do one of these:

1. The easy solution is to make a per-savefile directory.  You wouldn't need to worry about renaming each individual file, and you could still atomically rename the new backup dir over the old backup dir you're replacing.  That is, if your old backup is *bak/img.png* and *bak/main.xml*, write *bak.tmp/img.png* and *bak.tmp/main.xml* and rename *bak.tmp* to *bak*.
2. Name the new auxiliary files something else and let them coexist with the old ones for a little while.  That is, write *img.2.png* and *main.xml.tmp* (which should refer to *img.2.png*, not *img.png*) and only rename *main.xml.tmp* to *main.xml*.  Then delete *img.png*.
3. **addition:** If you don't have atomic renames, the next best thing extends on #2.  Whenever you save the project, give it a new name (e.g. *ver342.xml*).  When you load, just find the most recent XML *that is consistent* (i.e. its checksum verifies).  Keep around 2 or 3 to be safe.  Only delete an auto-save if you have successfully restored from a more-recent copy.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll probably have to go with some variant of option 2 because each autosave file set needs to share files with previous autosave file sets (there's a lot of data so I have to save only what has been changed); this makes using .zip files hard too. To further complicate matters, this will be running on Android as well i.e. an SD card which is usually fat32 formatted. I'm thinking even checksums is too paranoid myself as I've never read about any other android app doing this; if saving/loading was that volatile in general nothing would work very well I imagine.

Comment: @RichardNewton: With incremental updates to only some files, I agree that #2 is best.  As for low-level consistency, I don't know what kind of atomicity guarantees Android provides for FAT32 file systems on flash memory.

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused at how to proceed. I need autosave to be fast in that it will happen when a user gets a phone call (2 seconds maximum for about 2Mb of data) and also happen when the user is using the application. If I go crazy checking the checksum of a written file, performance is going to be a problem. I obviously don't want to have corrupt files but I need to find a balance. My gut tells me most applications don't do checksum checks and get away with it and this should work for me too, but I don't know for sure. I'm having no luck finding out which Android IO ops are atomic either...

Comment: Really, checksums are fast, and 2 MB isn't that much data.