# File become zero byte if system crashes in android

Tags: java, android

I am writing a object to a file in a separate thread and this thread executes in every one minute. Every thing is work fine but if system crashes(remove power supply) then the file(in which I am writing the object) size become zero byte on next reboot.

**My Code is:**

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/vis.ser");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
out.writeObject(/*An object*/);    
out.close();
```

Comment: Are you saving an object or a primitive type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use a checksum to ensure the file has been written correctly and use renaming as Whity suggests.

However, if you are saving a primitive type, then you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which will avoid your "0 bytes" problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116620/how-to-be-sure-a-file-has-been-successfully-written) will give you a broader idea about how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

So your worries that previous data destroyed and new was not yet saved?
Shell you try to write in tmp file and if u managed to close it simply rename?

Comment: I know this is the solution but i don't want to use it

Comment: thats traditional way. For example torrent download file into tmp file until it finishes. The problem u met is classical. Open file to write didnt manage to close gracefully  - file content lost. There also append boolean flag but I gues its not an option in your case.